# Azure Active Directory API - EC001 Claims Missing

Tags: api, azure-active-directory, claims

I have to call an API hosted (not by me) on an app on AAD. I can get the bearer access jwt token via the C# library IdentityModel and if I parse it I can see all claims in place (meaning the "Claims" property in the "JwtSecurityToken" object).

Then I try to call the API passing the bearer and I get a 401 Unathorized - EC001 claims missing.

I can't get why that is, can't find any doc about it and I can't understand whether it's my fault or might be due to the app config on AAD.

Could someone help me about it?
Thank you

Comment: Could you please provide more details on 1)how you getting JWT token via C# library  Please provide code.2)How you calling the api please provide more details ?.3) Do you have the authorize  permission to call the api?

Comment: I get the jwt token using

     var certificate = new ClientAssertionCertificate(ClientRealm, x509certificate);
                        authenticationResult = authcontext.AcquireTokenAsync(PublicApiRealm, certificate).Result;
                    return authenticationResult.AccessToken;

```

Comment: Then, i call the api

`using (var client = new HttpClient())
                {
                    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
                    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));
                    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", jwtToken);
                    var address = new Uri($"{ApiBasePath}{ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["CreateApi"]}");

                    var responseResult = client.PostAsync(address, requestBody).Result;
}`

Answer (score 1):

The error might be occurring because of the App configuration on Azure Active Directory.

The API might require some claims which might be missing in your JWT token.

For example,

•   **roles** and **wids** claims to validate that the user themselves has authorization to call the API

•   **aud** claim to ensure that the user intended to call your application

•   **scp** claim to validate that the user has granted the calling app permission to call your API

•   **appid** claim to ensure that the calling client is allowed to call the API

Please refer the below document for more information :

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/access-tokens

Comment: Parsing the token I have aud and appid but no scp, roles and wids... I'll have to ask the provider of the api... Thank you so much